# Setting name of downloaded file using DownloadManager

Tags: android

I am working on an android app in which I download a file using `DownloadManager` class.

**Problem**

I am passing the name I want to give to the downloaded file in the `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir` method of the `DownloadManager.Request` class instead of that name, downloaded file takes the `String` I pass in `setTitle` method of the `DownloadManager.Request` class as its name.

This problem only occurs when I the visibility of the notification of `DownloadManager` is set to `true`, otherwise the downloaded file takes the name I pass in `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir` method.

**Question**

Why is this happening and how can I set the name of the downloaded file?

**Code**

```
DownloadManager.Request downloadRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

downloadRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
downloadRequest.setTitle(currentApp.getAppNameEng());

downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
      Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
      currentApp.getAppNameEng() + ".apk"
);

final DownloadManager downloadManager =
                (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(downloadRequest);
```

Comment: Could you post your code ?

Comment: @ShivamVerma posted.

Comment: The code looks okay. I would suggest using a different file manager to check the name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method it is working:_

In this download path is image or video url and another isImage param is if it is image send true and if it is video send false..

private void downLoadImageVideo(String downloadPath, Boolean isImage) {

```
    Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(downloadPath);

    DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
    request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
    request.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
    request.setDescription(getString(R.string.downloading));
    request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(downloadPath));
    request.setMimeType(mimeType);

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    if (isImage) {
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/AppName", "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/AppName", "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    }


    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
}
```